# EditorFor with a variable length list - wrong data is displayed after deleting an item

Tags: asp.net-mvc, editorfor

I'm trying to create a form which will be used by clients to place an order for variable amount of models. It's similar to example from [Steve Sanderson's blog](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/), but I'm not using any javascript - I just have multiple submits in my form.

Everything works fine, I can add as many items as I want, but when I delete an item always the last one from list gets removed. Here's some code:

Fragment from `Create.aspx`:

```
<% for (int i = 0; i < Model.Input.Models.Count; i++ ){%>
  <%: Html.EditorFor(m => m.Input.Models[i])%>
  <p><input type="submit" name="deleteModel#<%:i%>" value="Delete" /></p>
<%}%>
```

Interesting fragment from `ModelCreateModel.ascx` EditorTemplate:

```
<div class="editor-field">
    <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name) %>
    <%: Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name) %>
</div>
```

In my `OrderCreateModel` I have a property `Input` of type `OrderCreateModel.InputModel` so `Model.Input.Models` is just a list of `ModelCreateModel`s

Now if I:

1. Add 3 models using this form (with names *AAA*, *BBB*, *CCC*)
2. Click a `delete#0` submit to remove model *AAA*

As a result I'll get editors for models *AAA* and *BBB*, but displays for models *BBB* and *CCC*. It's just too crazy for me! I've checked it with fiddler and this is really how the response looks like - it's not my browser's fault. Also, after debugging my code I'm 100% sure that I'm removing *BBB* model from my `Input.Models` before passing it to `View()`.

Any suggestions how can I fix this?

Note: I don't want to use javascript for this. It'll be added later to provide better user experience, but site has to work as well with javascript disabled.

**Edit:**

Controller's code:

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("Create")]
[MultipleSubmits(InputName = "deleteModel", Argument = "deleteModelNr")]
[Authorize(Roles = RoleHelper.Accountant + "," + RoleHelper.Admin)]
public ActionResult CreateDeleteModel(OrderCreateModel.InputModel input)
{
    var viewModel = new OrderCreateModel {Input = input};
    FillCreateModelWithMaps(viewModel, input.ClientId);

    var deleteModelNr = (int) ViewData["deleteModelNr"];

    if (input.Models.Count > deleteModelNr)
        input.Models.RemoveAt(deleteModelNr);

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

`MutlipleSubmitsAttribute` inherits from `ActionNameSelectorAttribute` and here it extracts `deleteModelNr` from submits name and puts it in `ViewData`.

`FillCreateModelWithMaps` just fills `viewModel.ExistingMaps` with data.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your action:

ViewData.ModelState.Clear();

Answer (score 0):

`EditorFor()` and some other helper methods use `ViewData.ModelState` instead of the Model itself. So it seems changes to the Model are not really supported. To my mind this looks like a major bug in MVC.